# Can not add property 2, object is not extensible Array.push

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm trying to add an array to a global array. Then save that array to `AsyncStorage`. But I can't seem to be able to do that and I'm not sure why.

It seems to have a problem with pushing to that array.

I have tried pushing any key to it, but still that didn't fix my problem.

```
//for saving all transactions

let exchanges =[ x = ''];
class AddScreen extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
i=0;
super(props);

this.state = {text: '',  name:'',amount:'',budget:'',date:'',geoloc:''};
}

setName = () => {
const {text} = this.state;
AsyncStorage.setItem('name', text);
alert("data Saved " +text);
}

SavetoGlobalTransaction = () => {
//get everything from state
const {name} = this.state;
const {amount} = this.state;
const {budget}= this.state;
const {date}= this.state;
const {geoloc}= this.state;

trans = {
  name :this.name,amount:this.amount,budget:this.budget,date:this.date,geoloc:this.geoloc
}

exchanges.push(trans);

AsyncStorage.setItem('ex', exchanges);
alert("data Saved " +exchanges[0].name);
}
```

This is the kind of error that I get:

```
Cannot add property 2, object is not extensible
    Array.push
     <anonymous>
    Object.AddScreen._this.SavetoGlobalTransaction [as onPress]
     f6f1eeda-c1a7-4b01-ba0e-76dc313c6ebd:2177:19
    Object.touchableHandlePress
     f6f1eeda-c1a7-4b01-ba0e-76dc313c6ebd:15410:40
    Object._performSideEffectsForTransition
     f6f1eeda-c1a7-4b01-ba0e-76dc313c6ebd:14990:16
    Object._receiveSignal
     f6f1eeda-c1a7-4b01-ba0e-76dc313c6ebd:14916:14
    Object.touchableHandleResponderRelease
     f6f1eeda-c1a7-4b01-ba0e-76dc313c6ebd:14795:12
    Object.invokeGuardedCallbackImpl
     f6f1eeda-c1a7-4b01-ba0e-76dc313c6ebd:27408:16
    invokeGuardedCallback
     f6f1eeda-c1a7-4b01-ba0e-76dc313c6ebd:27499:37
    invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError
     f6f1eeda-c1a7-4b01-ba0e-76dc313c6ebd:27503:31
    executeDispatch
     f6f1eeda-c1a7-4b01-ba0e-76dc313c6ebd:27697:9
```

Comment: Is the global variable the one inside asyncStorage?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot modify the array, you need to create a new array with the additional data and save that. Try using .concat or the spread operator.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to just use spread operator(...) and it will just bomb the values of your trans object and add it into the exchange array

```
exchanges.push(...trans);
```

This should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

I have hit the same error as yours. My way to resolve this is to deep clone the original array to a new one and then operate the new array and use the new array as the data source.

As for your code, you can deep clone the `AsyncStorage` and use the new array to insert your previous array.